# Issue BLOB data handle in Liquibase for Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, blob, liquibase

**BLOB Data** : Liquibase with Oracle

**Issue** : 
How to create a table contains a column as LOB( BLOB/CLOB) with "DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW"

**Description** : 
We are trying to create a table contains the BLOB data in Liquibase for Oracle DB 
Now challenge is that we need this particular column ( BLOB) should not contain the date in row, instead it should be linked to a table space. 
Means : We want to set the "DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW" for the BLOB Content

Now we are able to achieve the same if we run the SQL as follows for Oracle DB

```
CREATE TABLE DEVMDR1.VCH_ACTIVITY_DEFN
  (
    ...
    CREATE_TS  TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(50),
    DEFN_XML BLOB,
    MODIFIED_BY    VARCHAR2(50),
    MODIFY_TS      TIMESTAMP,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ("ACTIVITY_DEFN_KEY")   
  ) LOB ("DEFN_XML") STORE AS (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  CACHE  NOCOMPRESS ) ;
```

But we are unable to achieve the same using LIQUIBASE.

Can someone give views on the same as need to implement the same as the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a sql statement in separate file (e.g. VCH_ACTIVITY_DEFN.sql) and use [sqlFile](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) tag that allows you to specify any sql statements and have it stored external in a file.